# How do I change my default status in Windows 8 Messaging to available? It keeps changing my staus to invisible

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-messaging-app

I just bought a new computer with Windows 8, and it is driving me relatively nuts. The messaging app would be convenient, were it not for the fact that it keeps automatically changing my status to invisible and I keep having to change it back to available-sometimes in the middle of a conversation if I click out of the window. Does anyone know how I can change the default status to available?

Comment: Is the Skype Metro app also running? Maybe the two are conflicting. Can you completely close Skype and then try the Messaging app?